# Ajax doesn't show PHP data

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I'm in a little trouble here. I'm trying to use ajax to get data from PHP server, that it gets from Mysql database; and then display into a specific html tag place. But, for some reason, nothing is showed off to html. I tested the PHP page and it works correctly. The point is, when ajax should get the data and display, it seems that there's nothing at database.

This is my html target :

```
<div class="container">

        <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Título</th>
                        <th>Curiosidade</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>

                </tbody>
            </table>
</div>
```

This is my Ajax Script:

```
   function readData() {

          $.ajax({                                      
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            url: 'http://localhost/Gravidapp/php/read.php',                                           
            success: function(data){

              $('tbody').html(data);

            },
            error: function(xhr,desc,err){
                ajax.error(xhr);
                ajax.error(desc, err);
            } 
              });
          };
```

This is my PHP file:

```
   <?php

        require("bdconn.php");
        $pdo = new db();

        $pdo->mysql->beginTransaction();

        $rs = $pdo->mysql->query("select * from timeline");
        $rs->execute();

        while($row = $rs->fetch()){
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['titulocuriosidade']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['curiosidade']?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
                  }

   ?>
```

Any suggests?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think PHP will only echo once.

Comment: As a start, you seem to want GET rather than POST. After that, check in the developer console to see if you are receiving data.

Comment: Also, start off by having the php return a hard-coded response to rule out database problems, then give your while loop syntax a checkup. This article may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587701/template-and-while-loops

Comment: Could you try building the string (HTML) first and then `echo` afterwards?

Comment: As @greendemiurge said you can debug in the developer console. Inside success function, you can put: console.log(data); and when you load the page you give a right-click on the page and inspect. Then you can check on the console the return of console.log.

Comment: Don't respond multiple times to XHR, instead collect the response data to a single string, and echo that string.

Comment: Well, I tried these...Apparently,it's normal. There's no syntax error. But, the problem goes on.

Comment: The browser, is it IE?

Comment: it's Opera browser.

Answer (score 0):

If the php response doesn't have the data type on headers ajax response could send an error.

Try setting `dataType="text html"` on your ajax request this will try to convert the response from text to html

also try to print errors on console to show whats is going wrong.

```
error: function(xhr,desc,err){
    console.log(desc);
}
```

see dataType on: [JQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: still goes on...as I said above, the code seems to be normal. the console nothing shows too. so, it appears to be ok.

Comment: Try using `complete` callback to see if there throws some status.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is: when you make an ajax call you must have a return of some data in the php called. When you need to include html you can call a method that return to you a template already ready to be included in the current html page. You can have for example an index.html that will be included when you load your page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="data-ajax"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/timeline.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In you js timeline.js you will include in the current html page what has returned in the data of the ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "html",
    url: 'timeline.php',
    success: function (data) {
        $('#data-ajax').html(data);
    }
});
```

You will have also your php returning the html to be used in the ajax:

```
<?php

getTimelineData();

function getTimelineData() {
    //here you retrieve data from database
    $results = array(0 => 'first-result', 2 => 'second-result', 3 => 'third-result');

include_once 'timeline-data.php';
}
```

And finally your timeline-data.php file:

```
Here is your data!

<?php foreach($results as $result) { ?>

<?= $result ?>

<?php } ?>
```